# Qual é a melhor forma de atualizar um branch?

Tags: git

Atualmente quando vou atualizar um branch com as modificações que fiz em outro computador faço o sequinte:

`git fetch -p`

Então o `origin/branchName` e `branchName` estão separados sendo o `branchName` desatualizado (Um detalhe importante é que no branch eu não faço vários commits, e sim apenas um para fazer o rebase, quando dou commit uso `push origin branchName -f`)

Para juntar os `origin/branchName` e `branchName` eu faço o seguinte:

`git cehckout -B branchName origin/branchName`

Funcionar para mim funciona, mas estou fazendo isso certo? Há alguma forma de fazer isso melhor?

Answer (score 1):

O comando `git merge` já deve ser suficiente para atualizar seu branch.

[Segundo a documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-ltcommitgt82308203), se você não especificar um branch, o git irá fazer o merge do branch remoto do seu branch atual, que no seu caso será o `origin/branchName`.